# Can we run Selenium WebDriver Test case with IIS, instead of Visual Studio Development server

Tags: asp.net, iis, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am working with Selenium 2 WebDriver. Instead of UnitTest project, i initiate it from website because of following reasons:

1. It should automatically run every 24 hours. I have written some scheduling code using System.Threading.
2. Provide some UI to customer to run it intermediately when they require.
3. At every run an email would be sent as a part of test result.

My target site is: http://www.vroomvroomvroom.com.au

I have created a Class which has all the Selenium Code. I call that Class using System.Threading upon page load of default.aspx.

It works fine when i run default.aspx from visual studio by pressing F5 OR Ctrl+F5 i.e. with Visual Studio development server e.g. `http://localhost:3251/default.aspx`.

But, when i try to run it directly from IIS, with default port (80) e.g. `http://localhost/seleniumTest/default.aspx`, then it fails with following observation/error:

1. It runs the Selenium code to an extend, but doesn't show the broswer.
2. It fails after some steps with `No response from server for url http://localhost:7094/hub/session/4bbe4b0c-aeee-4fa3-8bc0-aae47c6869af/element`

It is possible what i am trying to achieve.

FYI: Let me know if further details are required.

Comment: Please post the error/execption/stack trace you are saying. Selenium has no dependencies with webservers -IIS, Apache, Glass Fish, WLS.. since its a stand alone agent.

Comment: There are 2 observations/errors: 1. It doesn't open the broswer, but test keeps running. I can verify this by associating the debugger. 2. It gives Response timeout after searching 3-4 fields/controls.

Comment: No response from server for url http://localhost:7094/hub/session/4bbe4b0c-aeee-4fa3-8bc0-aae47c6869af/element

Comment: @AshwinPrabhu : I have updated the complete question to provide more understanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have managed to find the solution myself.

Basically, RemoteWebDriver has to be used instead of FirefoxDriver.
Steps:

1. Change the initialization of FirefoxDriver to RemoteWebDriver as:

Change from

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

To

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
Uri url = new Uri("http://REMOTE_IP:4545/wd/hub");
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capability);
```

2. Download Selenium Standalone server and initiate it via command prompt using ~

```
java -jar E:\Software\selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar -interactive -port 4545
```

This approach has 2 benefits:

1. One could use the local IIS for running the test.
2. Test could be run remotely. Refer Selenium RC documentation. One could see the screenshots remotely using

   REMOTE_IP:4545/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html

I am thinking to modify the code of hub.html and client.js file used within it to provide a better Remote feel.

I hope this can be useful for others as well.

FYI:

1. IP address REMOTE_IP could be changed to any realtime IP address OR localhost. Use the above mentioned port while initiating the page request.
2. Start/Stop code of Standalone Server could be fitted inside the test, so that it is automatically started/stopped via batch file.
3. Keep the server running by not closing the command prompt.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was struggling with a similar situation where the driver did not start from the IIS.
In my Case just a small difference in the URL, that i set as follows: 

        Uri url = new Uri("http://LOCALHOST:4545/wd/hub");