# Python selenium webdriver script not working as expected when triggered from webapplication

Tags: asp.net, python-2.7, selenium, iis, permissions

I am working with Selenium 2 WebDriver.This project is like report automation which crops(Using PIL library) graph out of the webpage. Instead of UnitTest project, i initiate it from website because of following reasons:

1. Any user can run it at any time in 24 hour
2. No interruption of firefox while doing normal work

It works fine when i run default.aspx from visual studio by pressing F5 OR Ctrl+F5 i.e. with Visual Studio development server e.g. http://localhost:3251/default.aspx.

But, when i try to run it directly from IIS , with default port (80) e.g. http://localhost/seleniumTest/default.aspx,

1. With local system identity then it runs very very slowly almost an hour where as it should have executed within 4 min and cropped images are blank.

I tried changing identity with admin credentials to check if firefox is actually opening but it didn't . It opens in background (observed it from Task Manager).

So what could be the actual problem?If it has to do with firefox but script is working other than cropping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654038/can-we-run-selenium-webdriver-test-case-with-iis-instead-of-visual-studio-devel) helped me. You have to use remote webdriver, to use the remote WebDriver, you should have Selenium server running. 
code to use it

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver = webdriver.Remote(
   command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
   desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

Also you can refer for more details [on remote webdriver here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#using-selenium-with-remote-webdriver)