# Run selenium from client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I have built an ASP.net web app which implements Selenium driver .
my problem is that all the tests are running fine on local machine but after deployment and logging into my website as client and start the test the driver does not launch or make any reaction neither on the server machine nor the client machine

some of log file

> #Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
>    #Version: 1.0
>    #Date: 2017-08-15 02:24:24
>    #Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username >c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status >time-.taken
>   2017-08-15 02:24:24 10.0.2.15 GET / - 80 - 217.55.249.44 Mozilla/5.0+>>(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+>(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/60.0.3112.90+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 534
>   2017-08-15 02:24:24 10.0.2.15 GET /pages/css/Datafinderstyle.css - 80 - >217.55.249.44 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+>>(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/60.0.3112.90+Safari/537.36 >http:/// 200 0 0 198
>   2017-08-15 02:24:24 10.0.2.15 GET /favicon.ico - 80 - 217.55.249.44 >Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+>(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/60.0.3112.90+Safari/537.36 >/ 404 0 2 253
>   2017-08-15 02:24:28 10.0.2.15 GET / - 80 - 217.55.249.44 Mozilla/5.0+>(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+
>   2017-08-15 03:40:08 10.0.2.15 GET / - 80 - 217.55.249.44 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/60.0.3112.90+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 288
>   2017-08-15 03:40:15 10.0.2.15 POST / - 80 - 217.55.249.44 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/60.0.3112.90+Safari/537.36

Comment: Did you check the logs on the server where you are deploying the site?

Comment: Can you add more details, probably some relevant code where you are facing the issue with?

Comment: yes I did 
still not getting the problem

Comment: So I assume, I open your website, you want Selenium to a run a browser on my machine?

Comment: no the problem is that selenium does not run any where 
I want it to tart running on the server machine

Answer (score 0):

What operation system do you use on your local machine and your server? Sometimes such problems like yours are caused by:
a) bad permissions on the server to the files
b) firewall blocks your tests because of security issues
Check both this options and give feedback.

Comment: I checked permissions and fire wall and it did not make any difference

Comment: Someone has the same problem and the solutions is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654038/can-we-run-selenium-webdriver-test-case-with-iis-instead-of-visual-studio-devel, give me feedback if the problem is solved

Comment: mmm I saw this post before but when I try to initiate the driver as shown 
the cmd gives this error :'java ' is not recognized as an internal or external error command,operable program or batch file .

Comment: Yes because you need to add path to you Java in envirornment variables. You can do this using this examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation . After that run your Selenium again and give feedback.

Comment: I did !!
but it gives me an error in the cmd 
I have edited the post and attached a screen shot of the error

Comment: Starting from version 3 selenium server does not support option "-interactive". You can still use this option but with lower version of a selenium server driver.

Comment: I got it and the cmd says that selenium server is running now i got this error at client side :
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 
I think it is a permission issue now
I will try to solve and give you a feedback

Comment: I have watched task manger at server and it showed that the browser and the driver are launched  but they are not visible

Comment: What do you mean saying "they are not visible" ? Can't you ran any simple test connecting to the selenium Server on the specified port?

Comment: they seems as they are running in the back ground